# Vertical slider - adaptar tamanho

Tags: ios, swift, slider

Eu preciso que alguns sliders colocados via storyboard se adapte ao tamanho da tela quando colocados na posição vertical.

Afim de exemplo eu coloquei três sliders na tela e coloquei suas *contraints* de forma que eles possuem a mesma largura e fique a 20 px equidistantes, também estão a 20 px de cada borda da tela. Ficaram dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para que ficasse na posição vertical utilizei *CGAffineTransformMakeRotation* dessa forma para cada um:

```
@IBOutlet var slider01: UISlider! {
        didSet{
            slider01.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        }
    }
```

Após executar essa aplicação a tela fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu gostaria que os sliders ficassem a 20 px das bordas superiores e inferiores, dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Já resolveu? Nos dois últimos sliders vc setou para eles terem a mesma largura do primeiro.. mas vc setou o width do primeiro para um determinado valor?

Comment: A largura do primeiro slider é automática por conta das outras constraints já definidas.